# Instantiate class from class type

Tags: c#-4.0

What would be correct way to create new instance of the class from class type? The code below do not work, `CreateInstance` accepts only strings.

```
Type converter=null;    

converter = convertApiModelBase.Type;

return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(converter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(convertApiModelBase.Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329906%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

With the code you attached, use the The Type.FullName of the type to locate.

```
return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(converter.FullName);
```